# What does "may" indicate here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you tell me the function of "may" in the following quote? (Two lovers, a daughter of a duke and the duke's attendant, when finally left alone sing this lyric.)

```
     O rapture, when alone together
           Two loving hearts and those that bear them
      May join in temporary tether,
           Though Fate apart should rudely tear them.
    (The Gondoliers by Gilbert and Sullivan)
```